# Why this post is not "very low quality"

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, declined-flags

**Edit:**

```
**Am I misusing the “Very Low Quality” flag?**
```

that discussion is about "VLQ flags on questions is needed or not"

Couple of days back I was reviewing at old posts and I found below question

[**How to use SSL with a self-signed certificate in groovy?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242335/how-to-use-ssl-with-a-self-signed-certificate-in-groovy/3242369#3242369)

which has already and accepted answer with positive reputation, but apart from that there is another answer post I found for the question which is moreover like a comment or even it has down-voted.

Below is the snap shot:

[image]

So ***I flagged as low quality post, but when this morning I found the Flag is declined*** and says..

[image]

So, is it really good answer and I should accept that I added wrong flag on it?

Comment: If your VLQ flag was declined then that does not make the answer a "good answer". The answer could still be treated as an incorrect / not useful answer (and the number of downvotes do confirm this). However, the text of VLQ flag says "This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing". A moderator handling your flag did not agree that the answer has severe formatting or content problems in it. VLQ flags cannot be used for incorrect answers.

Comment: VLQ flags should *only* be used for posts that are gibberish. *That answer is not gibberish*.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I think..that discussion is about "VLQ flags on questions is needed or not".

Comment: @RDC: No its not.

Comment: You have to realize that the moderates aren't going to evaluate correctness when handling flags

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer whilst lacking in content is not of "very low quality".

Very Low Quality tends to refer to a very badly formatted post.

The post you reference is correctly formatted and an attempt to answer the question. Just because the answer is incorrect or lacking explanation does not in itself make the post of very low quality.

To quote the flag description "*This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing*". In this case the user could edit the post to include rational for his answer if comments were left asking for such.

---

Please note: This is just my interpretation of the Very Low Quality Flag.
I would happily be corrected as I believe *IMO* answers without explanation are low quality, but I guess not **Very** low quality.

Comment: This is the answer.  I'd decline your flag on the same grounds this user has brought up.

Comment: Well put.  I've made an effort to improve the answer being discussed to clarify how it relates to the question.

Comment: @ataylor: I think your edit is incorrect based on my understanding of Groovy. See the question or we can discuss here.

Answer (score 5):

This is neither an answer nor a comment.

If the question was about Curl, or some software relying on Curl, then this would be a badly-written (and perhaps correct, perhaps incorrect) answer. Writing “Run `curl` with the `--insecure` option, or add the line `insecure` to your `~/.curlrc`” would make the answer clearer — showing that it wasn't very low quality (i.e. unsalvageable).

But the question has nothing to do with Curl: it's about doing something in Java. So **it's irrelevant**. It's not going to help anyone, at least not here (it could of course be a useful answer on a question about accepting self-signed certificates with Curl).

There isn't a sharp threshold between obviously irrelevant answers (“the sky is blue” on a question about SSL in Java), answers whose irrelevance requires a very tiny bit of subject knowledge (Java is not Curl) to be determined, and answers whose irrelevance is due to a subtle point involving deeep subject knowledge. Answers of the first type are consensually considered noise and “very low quality” or “not an answer” (Meta is full of debate as to which one is appropriate, my [personal view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214583/unify-not-an-answer-and-very-low-quality-in-a-single-delete-flag) being that we should forget trying to cut the sea in two and just say that they're answers to be deleted). Answers of the third type are consensually wrong answers. Answers of the second type are not consensual — because that “type” is really “stuff that isn't clearly of the noise or wrong type”, and not a clear-cut separate type.

Does this post help anyone, even as an example not to do? No, so it's better off deleted. So stop worrying and continue flagging obviously worthless stuff like this. But you will get disagreement and the occasional declined flag.

Comment: "Other" flag probably would have been more appropriate here. The problem with flagging is if you pick the wrong reason, then your flag is declined. But it's so arbitrary it's hard to figure out sometimes.